# How to declare multiple arrays of different sizes in one loop?

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

I have a file in hex look like following.

**Part 1**

```
1F 00 1C 3A 1F 00 25 3A 1F 00 09 3A 1F 00 50 3A 
1F 00 5A 3A 1F 00 5C 3A 1F 00 5B 3A 1F 00 59 3A
1F 00 5D 3A 03 00 FE 0F 1F 00 01 30 1F 00 06 3A 
1F 00 11 3A 1F 00 44 3A 1F 00 4F 3A 1F 00 45 3A 
1F 10 56 3A 1F 10 54 3A 1F 00 03 30 1F 00 02 30 
03 00 55 3A 03 00 71 3A 1F 00 29 3A 1F 00 27 3A 
1F 00 2A 3A 1F 00 28 3A 1F 00 26 3A 1F 00 51 3A 
1F 00 08 3A 1F 00 24 3A 1F 00 21 3A 1F 00 16 3A
1F 00 17 3A 1F 00 18 3A 1F 00 19 3A 1F 00 0A 80
1F 00 48 3A 1F 10 58 3A 02 00 4D 3A 40 00 42 3A 
40 00 41 3A 1F 00 04 30 1F 10 00 80 03 00 01 80
02 01 FF 0F
```

**Part 2**

```
40 00 08 30 03 00 71 3A 03 00 55 3A 1F 00 02 30 
1F 00 03 30 1F 10 54 3A 1F 10 56 3A 1F 00 06 3A 
1F 00 01 30 03 00 FE 0F 02 01 FF 0F
```

**Part 3**

```
40 00 08 30 03 00 71 3A 03 00 55 3A 1F 00 02 30 
1F 00 03 30 1F 10 54 3A 1F 10 56 3A 1F 00 11 3A 
1F 00 06 3A 1F 00 01 30 03 00 FE 0F 02 01 FF 0F
```

**Part 4**

```
1F 00 5D 3A 03 00 71 3A 03 00 55 3A 1F 00 02 30 
1F 00 03 30 1F 10 54 3A 1F 10 56 3A 1F 00 45 3A 
1F 00 4F 3A 1F 00 44 3A 1F 00 11 3A 1F 00 06 3A 
1F 00 01 30 02 01 FF 0F
```

**Part 5**

```
40 00 08 30 1F 00 03 30 1F 00 02 30 1F 00 01 30 
02 01 FF 0F
```

My file has so many data parts like above. Each data part ending with bytes `02 01 FF 0F`. Here I am showing only five parts.

Each time I don't know how many bytes are available in each data part. All the parts are together in one file. I want to read all of the parts and store all parts in a separate memory, i.e. array or linked list, so that I am become able to access all bytes.

My code is as follows:

```
int n = 500;     //where n is the number of parts in my file
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  rewind(pFile);
  fread(&a, 1, 4, pFile);
  if((a==0x0FFF0102) || (a==0x8004001F) || (a==0x800D001F))
  {
    continue;
  }
  fseek(pFile, -4, SEEK_CUR);
  while(a!=0x0FFF0102)
  {
    fread(&a, 1, 4, pFile);
    // now  what can I do here. where I store all above hex data.

  }
}
```

Comment: I've no idea what you are asking

Comment: Read the entire data and store *offsets* to the start of each item in an array. Make the array size + 1 and write the end in the last one, so you can use `array[i+1]-array[i]` as size of `array[i]`.

Comment: in While loop i am reading each data part until i find the byte 02 01 FF 0F . Now tell me ,how can i store each part in array or in alinked list.

Comment: Since the size is unknown until runtime, you'll need some kind of dynamic data structure to store it -- something like a `std::vector` perhaps? You can just do a `std::copy` from each 4 byte chunks and append it to the vector.

Comment: To extend @Jongware answer, you can read the file a first time, and just store (in a linked list, or an array `offsets`) all the offsets position of the byte "02 01 FF 0F". Then, you read your file again to store your data in an array, using by exemple  `fread(data[i], 1, offset[i+1] - offset[i], pFile)`

Comment: @greatwolf why giving answer for C++, when OP wants C?

Comment: Are you saying that the file _is_ formatted in hex, or that it is binary data that would look like you show it if it was formatted in hex?  Given the code, I think you must mean the latter, but it is not immediately clear from the wording in the question. Assuming that the file is binary data, are you guaranteed that the end marker starts on a multiple of 4 bytes (offset = 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, ...)? That is important; it simplifies the problem. Finally, was the data generated and written on the same type of machine as you're reading it on? You might need to worry about big-endian vs little-endian.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I am removed the last byte of 'part 3' . Yes each part contains number of bytes in multiple of four. And i am reading in little indian .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer stands if your file is much smaller than the memory available on your machine.

1. Allocate a large buffer that you think will fit the entire file using `calloc()`.
2. Start reading the file by chunks.

   - Keep track of how much you have read.
3. Put the read contents into the allocated buffer.

   - if the buffer can't fit the read data, use `realloc()` to enlarge the buffer
4. Once you have read the entire file, create another array, this time of `char*` pointers - for the parts start list
5. Add pointer to the beginning of the read buffer to the parts start list
6. Start reading the read buffer and search for the `02 01 FF 0F` part-ending bytes
7. Add the location after each found byte sequence to the parts start list. Again, realloc as needed.
8. Replace the end bytes with '\0' if the file is a text file; otherwise do nothing
9. Repeat until reached end of the buffer
10. treat each entry in parts start list as a string and perform your operations on it. Its end is marked by the start of next entry.

Comment: Could you please write the code for the above given data. Each part store in separate array.

Answer (score 1):

I am building my answer upon [Dariusz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19541518/296974). Normally I would put that into a comment, but I write too much for it.

The problem is that, depending on your program's general usage of memory, `malloc()`ing smaller chunks of memory might be more successful.

1. `malloc()` enough memory so that the pointers will fit in.
2. Read chunk by chunk into some temporary buffer.
3. Once you have a full chunk, `malloc()` memory for it and put the data in. Remember to note the size somewhere.
4. Put that pointer into the pointer list, `realloc()`ing it as needed.

Dariusz' solution has advantages - e.g., you can get the size of the chunks by just subtracting pointers - but, as said, one large chunk for the while file *might* lead to problems, depending on the file size.

---

Another solution would be to use `mmap()`, which allows you to map a disk file in memory.

This gives you a pointer to virtual memory where you exactly find the bytes from your disk file.

In this case, stick closer to Dariusz' answer, starting at point 4.

Answer (score 1):

*Sledgehammer, meet Nut; Nut, Sledgehammer.*

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "imageprt.h"
#include "stderr.h"

enum { EOS_MARKER = 0x0FFF0102 };

typedef struct Section
{
    size_t   length;
    int32_t *data;
} Section;

typedef struct Description
{
    size_t  n_sections;
    Section *sections;
    int32_t *data;
} Description;

static void free_description(Description *dp);
static Description *read_description(FILE *fp, char const *fn);
static void dump_description(char const *tag, Description const *desc);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        FILE *fp = fopen(argv[i], "rb");
        if (fp == 0)
            err_sysrem("Failed to open file %s for reading\n", argv[i]);
        else
        {
            Description *desc = read_description(fp, argv[i]);
            dump_description("Description", desc);
            fclose(fp);
            free_description(desc);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}

static void dump_description(char const *tag, Description const *desc)
{
    assert(desc != 0);
    printf("%s: %p\n", tag, (void *)desc);
    printf("Number of sections: %zu\n", desc->n_sections);
    if (desc->n_sections != 0)
    {
        assert(desc->sections != 0);
        assert(desc->data != 0);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < desc->n_sections; i++)
        {
            size_t offset = (desc->sections[i].data - desc->data) * sizeof(int32_t);
            printf("Section %zu:\n", i);
            image_print(stdout, offset, (char *)desc->sections[i].data,
                desc->sections[i].length * sizeof(int32_t));
        }
    }
}

static void free_description(Description *dp)
{
    assert(dp != 0);
    free(dp->sections);
    free(dp->data);
    free(dp);
}

static Description *read_description(FILE *fp, char const *fn)
{
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size_t n_bytes = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    if (n_bytes % sizeof(int32_t) != 0)
    {
        err_remark("Length of file (%zu) is not a multiple of %zu bytes\n",
                n_bytes, sizeof(int32_t));
        return 0;
    }

    Description *desc = (Description *)calloc(1, sizeof(Description));
    if (desc == 0)
        err_syserr("Failed to allocate memory\n");

    desc->data = (int32_t *)malloc(n_bytes);
    if (desc->data == 0)
        err_syserr("Failed to allocate memory\n");

    size_t n_read = fread(desc->data, 1, n_bytes, fp);
    if (n_read != n_bytes)
        err_syserr("Short read on file %s\n", fn);

    //image_print(stderr, 0, (char *)desc->data, n_bytes);

    /* All data in memory — how many sections? */
    size_t n_values = n_bytes / sizeof(int32_t);
    size_t n_sects = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_values; i++)
    {
        if (desc->data[i] == EOS_MARKER)
            n_sects++;
    }
    //err_remark("Found %zu sections\n", n_sects);

    desc->sections = (Section *)malloc(n_sects * sizeof(Section));
    size_t sec_num = 0;
    int32_t p_value = EOS_MARKER;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_values; i++)
    {
        if (p_value == EOS_MARKER)
        {
            //err_remark("Found EOS_MARKER: section %zu, index %zu\n", sec_num, i);
            //image_print(stderr, 0, (char *)&desc->data[i], (n_values - i) * sizeof(int32_t));
            desc->sections[sec_num].data = &desc->data[i];
            //err_remark("Section %zu: data %p\n", sec_num, (void *)desc->sections[sec_num].data);
            if (i > 0)
            {
                assert(sec_num > 0);
                desc->sections[sec_num-1].length = &desc->data[i] - desc->sections[sec_num-1].data;
                //err_remark("Section %zu: length %zu\n", sec_num-1, desc->sections[sec_num-1].length);
            }
            sec_num++;
        }
        p_value = desc->data[i];
    }
    assert(sec_num == n_sects);
    desc->sections[sec_num-1].length = &desc->data[n_values] - desc->sections[sec_num-1].data;

    if (p_value != EOS_MARKER)
        err_syserr("The file %s did not finish with the section marker!\n", fn);
    desc->n_sections = n_sects;

    return desc;
}
```

The header `imageprt.h` declares 'image_print()`, a function in my personal library that formats hex dumps. The header`stderr.h`defines error reporting functions such as`err_remark()`and`err_syserr()` (which report a message and continue, and report a message, the system error, and stop, respectively).

The code slurps the entire file into a single chunk of memory, then divvies it up into sections.  The `Description` structure contains the description.  The code scans the data twice while reading (and again for printing).  If the file is going to be multiple gigabytes, it might be better to build up the sections list in a single pass.  You could also consider memory mapping the file.

#### Hex dump of input data

```
0x0000: 1F 00 1C 3A 1F 00 25 3A 1F 00 09 3A 1F 00 50 3A   ...:..%:...:..P:
0x0010: 1F 00 5A 3A 1F 00 5C 3A 1F 00 5B 3A 1F 00 59 3A   ..Z:..\:..[:..Y:
0x0020: 1F 00 5D 3A 03 00 FE 0F 1F 00 01 30 1F 00 06 3A   ..]:.......0...:
0x0030: 1F 00 11 3A 1F 00 44 3A 1F 00 4F 3A 1F 00 45 3A   ...:..D:..O:..E:
0x0040: 1F 10 56 3A 1F 10 54 3A 1F 00 03 30 1F 00 02 30   ..V:..T:...0...0
0x0050: 03 00 55 3A 03 00 71 3A 1F 00 29 3A 1F 00 27 3A   ..U:..q:..):..':
0x0060: 1F 00 2A 3A 1F 00 28 3A 1F 00 26 3A 1F 00 51 3A   ..*:..(:..&:..Q:
0x0070: 1F 00 08 3A 1F 00 24 3A 1F 00 21 3A 1F 00 16 3A   ...:..$:..!:...:
0x0080: 1F 00 17 3A 1F 00 18 3A 1F 00 19 3A 1F 00 0A 80   ...:...:...:....
0x0090: 1F 00 48 3A 1F 10 58 3A 02 00 4D 3A 40 00 42 3A   ..H:..X:..M:@.B:
0x00A0: 40 00 41 3A 1F 00 04 30 1F 10 00 80 03 00 01 80   @.A:...0........
0x00B0: 02 01 FF 0F 40 00 08 30 03 00 71 3A 03 00 55 3A   ....@..0..q:..U:
0x00C0: 1F 00 02 30 1F 00 03 30 1F 10 54 3A 1F 10 56 3A   ...0...0..T:..V:
0x00D0: 1F 00 06 3A 1F 00 01 30 03 00 FE 0F 02 01 FF 0F   ...:...0........
0x00E0: 40 00 08 30 03 00 71 3A 03 00 55 3A 1F 00 02 30   @..0..q:..U:...0
0x00F0: 1F 00 03 30 1F 10 54 3A 1F 10 56 3A 1F 00 11 3A   ...0..T:..V:...:
0x0100: 1F 00 06 3A 1F 00 01 30 03 00 FE 0F 02 01 FF 0F   ...:...0........
0x0110: 1F 00 5D 3A 03 00 71 3A 03 00 55 3A 1F 00 02 30   ..]:..q:..U:...0
0x0120: 1F 00 03 30 1F 10 54 3A 1F 10 56 3A 1F 00 45 3A   ...0..T:..V:..E:
0x0130: 1F 00 4F 3A 1F 00 44 3A 1F 00 11 3A 1F 00 06 3A   ..O:..D:...:...:
0x0140: 1F 00 01 30 02 01 FF 0F 40 00 08 30 1F 00 03 30   ...0....@..0...0
0x0150: 1F 00 02 30 1F 00 01 30 02 01 FF 0F               ...0...0....
0x015C:
```

#### Example output

```
Description: 0x7fc58bc03a20
Number of sections: 5
Section 0:
0x0000: 1F 00 1C 3A 1F 00 25 3A 1F 00 09 3A 1F 00 50 3A   ...:..%:...:..P:
0x0010: 1F 00 5A 3A 1F 00 5C 3A 1F 00 5B 3A 1F 00 59 3A   ..Z:..\:..[:..Y:
0x0020: 1F 00 5D 3A 03 00 FE 0F 1F 00 01 30 1F 00 06 3A   ..]:.......0...:
0x0030: 1F 00 11 3A 1F 00 44 3A 1F 00 4F 3A 1F 00 45 3A   ...:..D:..O:..E:
0x0040: 1F 10 56 3A 1F 10 54 3A 1F 00 03 30 1F 00 02 30   ..V:..T:...0...0
0x0050: 03 00 55 3A 03 00 71 3A 1F 00 29 3A 1F 00 27 3A   ..U:..q:..):..':
0x0060: 1F 00 2A 3A 1F 00 28 3A 1F 00 26 3A 1F 00 51 3A   ..*:..(:..&:..Q:
0x0070: 1F 00 08 3A 1F 00 24 3A 1F 00 21 3A 1F 00 16 3A   ...:..$:..!:...:
0x0080: 1F 00 17 3A 1F 00 18 3A 1F 00 19 3A 1F 00 0A 80   ...:...:...:....
0x0090: 1F 00 48 3A 1F 10 58 3A 02 00 4D 3A 40 00 42 3A   ..H:..X:..M:@.B:
0x00A0: 40 00 41 3A 1F 00 04 30 1F 10 00 80 03 00 01 80   @.A:...0........
0x00B0: 02 01 FF 0F                                       ....
Section 1:
0x00B4: 40 00 08 30 03 00 71 3A 03 00 55 3A 1F 00 02 30   @..0..q:..U:...0
0x00C4: 1F 00 03 30 1F 10 54 3A 1F 10 56 3A 1F 00 06 3A   ...0..T:..V:...:
0x00D4: 1F 00 01 30 03 00 FE 0F 02 01 FF 0F               ...0........
Section 2:
0x00E0: 40 00 08 30 03 00 71 3A 03 00 55 3A 1F 00 02 30   @..0..q:..U:...0
0x00F0: 1F 00 03 30 1F 10 54 3A 1F 10 56 3A 1F 00 11 3A   ...0..T:..V:...:
0x0100: 1F 00 06 3A 1F 00 01 30 03 00 FE 0F 02 01 FF 0F   ...:...0........
Section 3:
0x0110: 1F 00 5D 3A 03 00 71 3A 03 00 55 3A 1F 00 02 30   ..]:..q:..U:...0
0x0120: 1F 00 03 30 1F 10 54 3A 1F 10 56 3A 1F 00 45 3A   ...0..T:..V:..E:
0x0130: 1F 00 4F 3A 1F 00 44 3A 1F 00 11 3A 1F 00 06 3A   ..O:..D:...:...:
0x0140: 1F 00 01 30 02 01 FF 0F                           ...0....
Section 4:
0x0148: 40 00 08 30 1F 00 03 30 1F 00 02 30 1F 00 01 30   @..0...0...0...0
0x0158: 02 01 FF 0F
```

Yes, the same `image_print()` function is used in my hex dump program as in this program.